# GitLab CI/CD - doctrine/dbal and laminas/laminas-code PHP version problem

Tags: php, symfony, gitlab, composer-php, gitlab-ci

When I try to upload files with this CI/CD script:

```
before_script:
- apt-get update
- apt-get install zip unzip
- php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
- php composer-setup.php
- php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
- php composer.phar install

deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $FTP_USERNAME,$FTP_PASSWORD ****; mirror -Rnev ./ /sub/plusim --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/ "
  only:
    - master
```

This error appears to me:
[image: The error]

How can I fix it?
I don´t know where should I change the PHP version and how.
This project is done in Symfony 5.

PS: Sorry, if this is copied answer, but I can´t figure it out

EDITED:
I updated my script with:
`- php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs`

And it helped in some way, but there is still a problem:
[image]

Comment: It looks like it needs an earlier version of PHP. Can you switch that in GitLab? I assume you can change the build image in a YAML setting.

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message **in text form** and your debugging attempts

Comment: Also, by simply **reading** that errror message, I see some pretty obvious information - what have you tried to resolve that hints about the PHP version?

Answer (score 1):

Composer has a flag that can help in CI environments where the CI environment won't match your application environment. `--ignore-platform-reqs` will tell Composer to install your dependencies and ignore any php version or php-extension issues that might arise, and to just install the dependencies.

So the `composer install` line in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file can be:

```
- php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: at first I did this at my local project, it didn´t work so I asked here. Now I added that line into the script, but there is still some error.